# How to access each group separately from the below output

Tags: c++, c++11

Below is the code **using vectors to divide a N sized array into M size groups**. But my problem here is , i want to access each group individually. How to do that??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> split(const std::vector<T>& vec, size_t n)
{
std::vector<std::vector<T>> outVec;

size_t length = vec.size() / n;
size_t remain = vec.size() % n;

size_t begin = 0;
size_t end = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(n, vec.size()); ++i)
{
    end += (remain > 0) ? (length + !!(remain--)) : length;

    outVec.push_back(std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + begin, vec.begin() + end));

    begin = end;
}

return outVec;

}

#define Nsta 30
#define NGroups 5

int main(void)
{
std::vector<uint64_t> vector(Nsta);
std::iota(std::begin(vector), std::end(vector), 0);

std::vector<std::vector<uint64_t>> vecs(NGroups);
vecs = split(vector, NGroups);


for (uint64_t m = 0; m < vecs.size(); ++m) 
{
    for (auto i : vecs[m])
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
std::cout << std::endl;
}

 return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30

**Please help me with this!!**

Comment: not sure what you're asking. Accessing individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember you asked this question before as well, and at that time I commented that your desired output is not clear.
I would suggest you to edit your question, and add a few lines on "desired output". 
Till the time it is not clear, no one would be able to help.
I have went ahead with my understanding of your problem.

*"But my problem here is , i want to access each group group individually. How to do that??"*

As per my understanding, you want to access each group individually after splitting.
Your program is already depicting the correct logic.
I am not sure what you need after this.

So I have refactored your code, for better understanding. Hopefully it helps.

Your splitting logic is correct. 
It is returning back multiple groups, after splitting your original data.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> split(std::vector<T> const & vec, size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> outVec;

    size_t length = vec.size() / n;
    size_t remain = vec.size() % n;
    size_t begin = 0, end = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < std::min(n, vec.size()); ++i)
    {
        end += (remain > 0) ? (length + !!(remain--)) : length;
        outVec.push_back(std::vector<T>(vec.begin() + begin, vec.begin() + end));
        begin = end;
    }
    return outVec;
}
```

In the `main()` I have renamed a few variables and modified the code structure for better understanding.
You want to identify each **group** and use it.

```
int main(void)
{
    int const Nsta = 34;
    int const NGroups = 5;
    std::vector<uint64_t> data(Nsta);
    std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);

    // split function takes data and the number of groups to be made
    auto groups = split(data, NGroups);

    // we can extract each `group` from the `groups`, and use it as per our need
    for (auto const & group : groups)
    {
        // group contains a single group
        // it can be passed to another function, such as print_group, etc.
        print_group(group); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is how a function that would work on a group, can be designed.

```
template<typename T>
void print_group(std::vector<T> const & group)
{
    std::cout << "Group : [ ";
    for (auto const & element : group)
    {
        std::cout << element << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]" <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Apologies for not elaborating my query well. After splitting them into different groups, is it possible to store each group in separate vector/array?

Comment: It is already in a separate vector. When we iterate over `groups`, every `group` is a separate vector of type `std::vector<T>`. You can make copies of `group` and pass it around to other functions, like I have demonstrated in the `print_group()` function.